# Publish Android App in Visual Studio

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

In [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_2_-_signing_the_android_application_package/#Create_a_New_Keystore) tutorial, there is an option as `Publish Android App`
[image]

but in my Visual Studio there isn't an option for that.
[image]

What can be the reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article says that

> To publish an application, the build configuration must first be
>   changed to **Release**.

Can you check that build configuration is set to Release? Also, you must select the Xamarin.Android project for the menu item to be active.

Comment: Okey I have set the project to Release and restarted Visual Studio, then Tools/Android/Publish Android App... option became visible.