# Xamarin Android application not able to deploy

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have visual studio 2017 with following Xamarin version in system.

> Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2017 Version 15.6.1
>   VisualStudio.15.Release/15.6.1+27428.2002 Microsoft .NET Framework
>   Version 4.7.02556
>
> Xamarin   4.9.0.749 (9b0fce36d) Visual Studio extension to enable
>   development for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.
>
> Xamarin Designer   4.10.58 (cee1369d0) Visual Studio extension to
>   enable Xamarin Designer tools in Visual Studio.
>
> Xamarin.Android SDK   8.2.0.15 (HEAD/22d97e153) Xamarin.Android
>   Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.
>
> Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK   11.8.0.20 (1c6f300) Xamarin.iOS and
>   Xamarin.Mac Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.
>   And i have create simple Xamarin android with some .net class library add as reference.

After add class reference and going for project build it ask System.deployment dll not found like below error.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     Exception while loading assemblies: 
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly
>   'System.Deployment, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.  Perhaps it doesn't exist in the
>   Mono for Android profile? File name: 'System.Deployment.dll'    at
>   Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference
>   reference, ReaderParameters parameters)    at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences
>   (DirectoryAssemblyResolver resolver, ICollection`1 assemblies,
>   AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)    at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences
>
>   (DirectoryAssemblyResolver resolver, ICollection`1 assemblies,
>   AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)    at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver
>   resolver)

After adding system.deployment dll reference getting another too many dll reference. At last after added all dll getting build application successfully, but not able to start application.

Below output of deploying app...

> 03-23 10:56:13.195 D/Mono    ( 8597): Assembly Loader probing
>   location: 'System.Deployment'. 03-23 10:56:13.195
>   F/monodroid-assembly( 8597): Could not load assembly
>   'System.Deployment' during startup registration. 03-23 10:56:13.195
>   F/monodroid-assembly( 8597): This might be due to an invalid debug
>   installation. 03-23 10:56:13.195 F/monodroid-assembly( 8597): A common
>   cause is to 'adb install' the app directly instead of doing from the
>   IDE.

Comment: Can you try with release mode instead of Debug. Refer below link,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36889291/

Comment: thanks but i think it not working because application installed correctly, but not open properly. i will comment after check with release mode.I think may be issue with include reference library because i'm new in Xamarin.

Comment: After select release mode same problem coming, only see blank window open, application crash not open properly.